# Flutter (or general mobile dev) Material 3 working in Emulator but not on phone

Tags: android, flutter, material-ui, material-design

I'm still relatively new to flutter and working on my first projects. I updated my Flutter version and app which came with the new Material3 design language. I enabled it in my theme settings and all the new material 3 features are visible on my Emulator and iOS. Im mostly using the new buttons, switches, chips, and the way headers can expand and change color depending on the elements scrolling under.

I noticed that when I build my app to test on my Xiaomi and galaxy s21, both updated to the most recent software and have Android 13. They don't have any of the new elements, they use old switch designs and so on. I found other material3 apps that have the new look that works on the phones, so they should support it.

Ironically it works fine on iPhones.

I also tested if I enabled it properly in my theme settings and it seems to work fine, it switches between material 2 and 3 on the emulator.

Is there something I need to change so it builds with material 3 on the android app not just on the emulator?

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please check the `MaterialApp` widget. It should have `useMaterial3` set to `true`.

```dart
return MaterialApp(
      title: 'My App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
    );
```

In case you also have set the `darkTheme` property, it should also have `useMaterial3` property set to true.

```dart
darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(useMaterial3: true),
```

Comment: Yes, I have it set up like that, and switching useMaterial3 to true or false switches the design in the emulator so I know it works and its set up properly. But the final build on any of the phones is in material2.